# Understanding the WPF Dispatcher.BeginInvoke

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, dispatcher

I was under the impression that the `dispatcher` will follow the priority
of the operations queued it and execute the operations based on the priority
or the order in which the operation was added to the queue(if same priority)
until I was told that this is no the case in case of the `WPF UI dispatcher`.

I was told that if a operation on the UI thread takes longer duration say a database read 
the UI dispatcher simple tries to execute next set of operations in the queue.
I could not come to terms with it so decided to write a sample WPF application which contains a  button and three rectangles, on click of the button, the rectangles are filled with different colors.

```html
<StackPanel>
    <Button x:Name="FillColors" Width="100" Height="100" 
            Content="Fill Colors" Click="OnFillColorsClick"/>
    <TextBlock Width="100" Text="{Binding Order}"/>
    <Rectangle x:Name="RectangleOne" Margin="5" Width="100" Height="100" Fill="{Binding BrushOne}" />
    <Rectangle x:Name="RectangleTwo" Margin="5" Width="100" Height="100" Fill="{Binding BrushTwo}"/>
    <Rectangle x:Name="RectangleThree" Margin="5" Width="100" Height="100" Fill="{Binding BrushThree}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

and in the code-behind

```
private void OnFillColorsClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var dispatcher = Application.Current.MainWindow.Dispatcher;

    dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
    {
        //dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(SetBrushOneColor), (DispatcherPriority)4);
        //dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(SetBrushTwoColor), (DispatcherPriority)5);
        //dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(SetBrushThreeColor), (DispatcherPriority)6);

        dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(SetBrushOneColor));
        dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(SetBrushTwoColor));
        dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(SetBrushThreeColor));

    }), (DispatcherPriority)10);
}

private void SetBrushOneColor()
{
    Thread.Sleep(10 * 1000);
    Order = "One";
    //MessageBox.Show("One");
    BrushOne = Brushes.Red;
}

private void SetBrushTwoColor()
{
    Thread.Sleep(12 * 1000);
    Order = "Two";
    //MessageBox.Show("Two");
    BrushTwo = Brushes.Green;
}

private void SetBrushThreeColor()
{
    Thread.Sleep(15 * 1000);
    Order = "Three";
    //MessageBox.Show("Three");
    BrushThree = Brushes.Blue;
}

public string Order
{
    get { return _order; }
    set
    {
        _order += string.Format("{0}, ", value);
        RaisePropertyChanged("Order");
    }
}
```

The commented code works as expected the methods are invoked based on the `DispatcherPriority`  and I also get to see the screen refresh after each operation has been completed.
`Order` is `One, Two, Three`. Colors are drawn one after another.

Now the working code where the `DispatcherPriority` is not mentioned
( I assume it would default to `Normal`) the order is still `One, Two, Three` but if I show a `MessageBox` inside the methods, the
 `Thrid` popup is show first then `Two` then `One` but when I debug I could see the methods are
 invoked in the expected order (IntelliTrace even shows that a message box is shown but I don't see it on the screen at that time and see it only after the last operation is finished.) its just that the `MessageBox`es are shown in the reverse order.

Is it because `MessageBox.Show` is a blocking call and the operation are cleared after the message has been closed.
 Even then the order of the `MessageBox` should also be `One`, `Two and`Three` ?

Comment: This is simply affected by the order in which you close the message boxes.  Since the last one is on top, that's the first one you close.  Does not have anything to do with DispatcherPriority.

Comment: Yes..I thought so, but am not able to see the other `MessageBox`es before I close the topmost one.

Comment: @Vignesh.N does my answer explains your query?

Answer (score 7):

Before coming down to your code behavior it's a prerequisite to understand the priorities of `Dispatcher`. `DispatcherPriority` is divided into ranges as shown in below image.

[image: DispatcherPriority]

If you simply queue 4 actions to 4 above ranges on `Dispatcher`. the `Foreground` queue will get executed first, then the `Background` and then in last `Idle` queue. priority 0 will not get executed.

**Now your code:**

Three task are queued 1st in `background`, 2nd in `background` and 3rd in `foreground` queue. So 3rd will get executed first. then 2nd task cause it has higher priority then 1st task. I hope that clears it.

Although some more observation will help you understand it better like, what if you have set the priorities as 7,8 and 9. So as this is a foreground queue, 7 will get executed first then 7 and then 8. One by one and exclusively in that order and while 7 is getting executed, 8 and 9 will wait, meaning `foreground` queue will get executed synchronously to each another.

But `Background` and `Idle` queue will not behave in that way the where execution is asynchronous to other tasks and tasks will follow the priority. And first `Background` and the `Idle` queue.

Hope this explanation clarifies to some extent.

Comment: if this is true, order of the color and text on screen has to "Three Two One" which is not the case.

Comment: @Vignesh.N I think you didn't read the answer carefully.... the task are in foreground queue, they will get executed in the series they are queued. and output will be "one two three"

Answer (score 5):

This is because the first `MessageBox` is blocking the **UI thread**.

What `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke()` is doing under the hood is taking your delegate and scheduling it to be run on the main UI thread during it's next idle period. However, `MessageBox` will block whichever thread it is called from until it is closed. This means that the second `MessageBox` cannot be displayed until the first is cleared because the UI thread scheduler sees that the thread is already in use (waiting for the first `MessageBox` to be cleared) and can't execute the next delegate containing the second `MessageBox`.

Comment: If you were right, I would expect the message boxes to be in the order they have been called. Hence 1, 2, 3 not 3, 2 1...

Comment: Indeed, however the execution order problem here can most likely be traced to the nested BeginInvokes. The outer BeginInvoke is already ensuring that the code is running on the UI. Simply removing the inner BeginInvokes would be enough to ensure that the code is executed in order. Calling BeginInvoke from the UI thread could easily have unexpected behaviors since you're already on the UI thread.

Comment: You are absolutely right, I tried it myself. I also tried a few times to really understand what is going on behind the scenes in this case, but however I try to look at it I came to the same conclusion: It should be 1, 2, 3. Can you explain in more detail what is your model of the inner workings here? What happens exactly?