# Object reference not set to an instance of an object error wpf nunit testing

Tags: observablecollection

Why I am getting an error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object” when I am trying to clear the values of an observable collection?

```
if(testcollection.Count>0) testcollection.Clear();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the testcollection have value, that is not equals to null, then this may happened because of cross threading issue. Try to implement this with the help of Dispatcher.

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke();
```

Try the following link,

[link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28477112/object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object-error-wpf-nunit-testing)

[link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25979264/understanding-the-wpf-dispatcher-begininvoke)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the limited code you gave, it looks like testcollection is null when you are trying to access the count.  Try this:

```
if (testcollection != null && testcollection.Count > 0) testcollection.Clear();
```