# Long operation blocking when called inside BeginInvoke

Tags: c#, wpf, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library

My Program searches every Table&Row in an MDB for a given string. 
When i start the search (Search_Button_Click) the progressbar is not showing up and the ui is blocking (cant move the window). Cant get whats wrong.

`ListViewData` is an `ObservableCollection<ListViewData>`

```
     private async void Search_Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        LoadBar.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        await StartSearch();
        LoadBar.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
    }

    private async Task StartSearch()
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            SearchMDB();
        });
    }

    private void SearchMDB()
    {
        this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            ListViewData.Clear();

            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, DataTable> _KVP in MDBContent)
            {
                for (int RowIndex = 0; RowIndex < _KVP.Value.Rows.Count; RowIndex++)
                {
                    DataRow _DR = _KVP.Value.Rows[RowIndex];
                    for (int i = 0; i < _DR.ItemArray.Length; i++)
                    {
                        if (_DR[i].ToString().Contains(Search_TextBox.Text))
                        {
                            ListViewItemClass _LC = new ListViewItemClass();
                            _LC.Page = _KVP.Key;
                            _LC.Column = _DR.Table.Columns[i].ToString();
                            _LC.Row = (RowIndex + 1).ToString();
                            _LC.ItemValue = _DR[i].ToString();
                            ListViewData.Add(_LC);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }));
    }
```

Comment: You are executing search code in the UI thread. Dispatcher's begininvoke schedules lambda execution and exits thus your await completes almost immediately.

Comment: Is it bad that I laughed seeing the dispather.begininvoke wraped inside a task?

Comment: Your code isn't asynchronous. You run `SearchMDB` on the UI thread. BeginInvoke marshals the call back to the UI thread. It doesn't matter that you call `BeginInvoke` from inside a Task.Run. You add a small delay but everything still runs on the UI thread

Comment: What are you trying to do? If you try to perform a full text search over an entire Access table, you'll get slow performance no matter what. You could improve performance a lot if you let Access do its job.

Comment: You can also convert the entire `SearchMDB` method to a single LINQ query. which will be slightly faster. It can also be parallelized easily with a simple call to `.AsParallel()`, which can improve performance a lot

Comment: Simply adding items one by one may be enough to make the code run extremely slow. Each `Add` results to a change notification and a UI update

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is synchronous. `BeginInvoke` is used to marshal calls back to the UI thread. Using `Task.Run` to call `BeginInvoke` doesn't change anything.

I assume from the name `SearchMDB` that you are trying to perform a `LIKE` search on an MDB database. The best option is to let *Access* do this. Access has indexes. Your code doesn't. It's forced to scan all the data instead. Better yet, find a full-text-search library that can handle MDB files. Loading everything in memory can actually make things *slower*.

If you want this code to run as is, just use Task.Run and pass the filter string as a parameter to `SearchMDB`, eg `StartSearch(Search_TextBox.Text)` :

```
private async void Search_Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    LoadBar.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    await Task.Run(StartSearch(Search_TextBox.Text));
    LoadBar.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
}

private void SearchMDB()
{
    ListViewData.Clear();

    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, DataTable> _KVP in MDBContent)
    {
        .....
    }
}
```

Better yet, **avoid** the global ListViewData container. It's extremely hard to write correct multithreaded code when using global state. Error handling is also harder - what are you going to do if `SearchMDB` fails ?

Assuming `ListViewData` is a `List<ListViewItemClass>`, you should write :

```
private async void Search_Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    LoadBar.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    ListViewData=await Task.Run(StartSearch(Search_TextBox.Text));
    LoadBar.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
}

private List<ListViewItemClass> SearchMDB()
{
    var newData=new List<ListViewItemClass>();

    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, DataTable> _KVP in MDBContent)
    {
      for ()
      {
        .....
        newData.Add(_LC);
      }
    }
    return newData();
}
```

This way you avoid concurrency errors *and* won't mangle your UI if `SearchMDB` throws.

**UPDATE**

The entire method could be rewritten as a single LINQ query :

```
var items = from KeyValuePair<string, DataTable> pair in MDBContent
            from DataRow row in pair.Value.Rows
            from DataColumn column in pair.Value.Columns
            let field=row[column].ToString()
            where field.Contains(searchText)
            select new ListViewItemClass
            {
                Page = pair.Key,
                Column = column.Caption,
//                Row = (RowIndex + 1).ToString(),
                ItemValue = field
            };
```

Not only is it clearer what is going on, you can easily convert it to PLINQ with a single call to `.AsParallel(), eg :

```
var items = from KeyValuePair<string, DataTable> pair in MDBContent.AsParallel()
            from DataRow row in pair.Value.Rows
            from DataColumn column in pair.Value.Columns
            let field=row[column].ToString()
            where field.Contains(searchText)
            select new ListViewItemClass
            {
                Page = pair.Key,
                Column = column.Caption,
//                Row = (RowIndex + 1).ToString(),
                ItemValue = field
            };
return items.ToList();
```

Notice that there is no `Row` field. Table rows *don't* have row indexes. Their position in the results is controlled by the `ORDER BY` clause. Without it, the database *can* and *will* return results out of order.

You can introduce a row index if you use the `Select()` overload that passes an inded as well as the item to project :

```
var items = from pair in MDBContent.AsParallel()
            let indexedRows =pair.Value.Rows.OfType<DataRow>().Select((row,idx)=>new {Row=row,Idx=idx})                
            from indexedRow in indexedRows
            from DataColumn column in pair.Value.Columns
            let field=indexedRow.Row[column].ToString()
            where field.Contains(searchText)
            select new ListViewItemClass
            {
                Page = pair.Key,
                Column = column.Caption,
                Row = (indexedRow.Idx +1).ToString(),
                ItemValue = field
            };
```

**UPDATE 2**

A comment in the other question shows that `ListViewData` is an ObservableCollection. This doesn't change anything. The data should still be processed on the side. `ObservableCollection` is meant to observe individual item changes.

In this case the entire collection changes. The easiest way to handle this is to replace the collection and raise a notification that its corresponding property changed, forcing the UI to reload the data. That's how WPF data binding works anyway, by binding to *properties* instead of fields. It's also a lot cheaper - clearing the collection and adding items one by one raises a *lot* of notifications.

The click event handler should be changed to :

```
private async void Search_Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    LoadBar.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    var data=await Task.Run(StartSearch(Search_TextBox.Text));

    ListViewData=new ObservableCollection(data);

    //Raise a change notification if `ListViewData` isn't a property
    //or doesn't raise the event itself
    //RaisePropertyChanged("ThatPropertyName);

    LoadBar.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
}
```

Comment: FYI - OP has stated in the other answer that ``ListViewData`` is of type ``ObservableCollection<ListViewItemClass>``

Comment: The OP should update the question. This doesn't change the answer though. ObservableCollection is meant for scenarios where only individual items change. When the entire collection changes, it should be replaced and a different notification raised. That's how MVVM works anyway - by binding to specific properties and their change notifications

Answer (score 2):

Two issues I can see:

A). SearchMDB() method is already being executed asynchronously. You can remove the `this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke()` line since you're falling back to run on the UI thread again.

B). BUT! You're updating your UI in that delegate! A better practice would be if the async thread fetched all the data you need from the DB (create a small DTO class if you need), and then you populate/refresh the ListView on the UI thread.

```
private async Task StartSearch()
{
    var data = await SearchAndFetchMDBDataAsync();
    RefreshListView(data);
}

private Task<List<object>> SearchAndFetchMDBDataAsync()
{
    return Task.Run(() =>
    {
        List<MdbDto> data = new List<MdbDto>();

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, DataTable> _KVP in MDBContent)
            // ...

        return data;
    });
}
```

Comment: "You're updating your UI in that delegate." Where exactly is that?

Comment: @Clemens ``ListViewData`` is probably a ``ListView`` in the ``UI``

Comment: Certainly not, a ListView has no Clear and Add methods.

Comment: `this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke()` is a call to run a delegate on the UI thread, https://stackoverflow.com/a/32489450/1380061

Comment: @Clemens found it ``Search_TextBox.Text``

Comment: @Rand Good catch. The Text property value should be put in a local variable before running the Task. Then Dispatcher.Invoke could simply be omitted.

Comment: which is why he probably threw that 'Dispatcher.BeginInvoke()' in there to make it work.. (just a guess)

Comment: Why the double async/await? ``SearchAndFetchMDBData`` could just return the ``Task``

Comment: ListViewData is a ObservableCollection<ListViewItemClass>. The ListView is bound to ListViewData. The Dispatcher was need because i used Search_TextBox.Text in SearchMDB. As Clemens said i removed it and pass the string as parameter